# How to see if a value in a spreadsheet cell is present in its corresponding PDF via Python?

Tags: python, excel, pdf, pdfminer

I want to see if the company's revenue is listed in its corresponding PDF. And be able to indicate in Column D if the revenue listed is present or not.

Please see spreadsheet below
[image]

I was wondering if there was a solution in Python for my situation?

All values in the PDF are typed in, so it should be scrapable

Comment: By "All values in the PDF are typed in" you mean that the pdf contain form definitions and the values have been filled into those form fields? Or might they also be "typed in" using free-text annotations?

Comment: @mkl Yes I mean that the pdf contain form definitions and the values have been filled into those form fields

Comment: Ok, is the form type (the native PDF format) AcroForm or (the more dynamic but completely separately defined) XFA?

Comment: @mkl It is AcroForm (native Pdf)